# How to show name in google analytics referral section?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, tracking, affiliate

I have created a affiliate tracking platform which tracks the clicks on links and I have setup the Google Analytics code on landing page.
When some one clicks on the link of tracking platform it redirects to the landing page having GA tracking code. 
Now when I check in GA it does not show in referrals from tracking platform but it shows direct traffic.
I want my affiliate tracking platform to be shown in referral traffic in GA.
Please help me resolving this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If a referral is not showing up in your reports, there are 2 possible reasons:

- It is an HTTP page redirecting to an HTTPS page. The browser strips the `Referer` header in the HTTPS request, and thus Google Analytics recognises it as a `(direct)` visit
- There are a series of redirects happening between the source site and your site. One or more of the redirects may be stripping out the `Referer` header

Your problem could be due to one or both of the above

Comment: thanks for reply. The redirect here I am using is server side. The page don't get download to the browser and I am using Nginx server as reverse proxy to node js server.

Comment: It would be useful if we could look at your origin page and the ultimate landing page. We would need to look at the Network console to identify the redirects, and to identify what happens to the `Referer` header at each step